# Construction of measure in Folland's Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Folland's Real analysis, page 20. He defined a equivalence class on $[0,1)$ such that $x\sim y$ iff $x-y$ is rational. Let $N$ be a subset of $[0,1)$ that contains precisely one member of each equivalence class. Then let $R=\Bbb Q \cap[0,1)$, and for each $r\in R$  let $N_r=\{x+r:x\in N\cap [0,1-r)\} \cup \{x+r-1:x\in N\cap[1-r,1)\}$. Then he said every $x\in[0,1)$ belongs to precisely one $N_r$. I am wondering why every $x\in N_r$ for some $r$.

Comment: An equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $X$ partitions $X$ into equivalence classes.

Comment: $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, so the set $[0,1)$ is partitioned into equivalence classes of $\sim$. For every $y \in [0,1)$, $N$ contains exactly one member of the equivalence class of $y$, say $x$. Then $y \sim x$ and $y =x + r$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. So we'd like to say that $y \in N_r$, but there's a slight subtlety, which accounts for the slightly strange definition of $N_r$ (to my understanding). Namely, $r = y - x$, so $r \in [-1,1]$, whereas $R = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1)$. In case $r \in [-1,0)$, replace $r$ by $r'=r+1 \in [0,1)$ and write $y = x+r = x+r'-1$.

Comment: If $r \in [0,1)$, we have $y = x+r$ with $x = y-r \in [-r,1-r) \cap N = [0,1-r) \cap N$; on the other hand, if $r \in [-1,0)$, we have $y = x+r'-1$ with $x = y+1-r' \in [1-r',2-r') \cap N = [1-r',1) \cap N$. In either case, this shows that $y \in N_r$ for some $r \in R$.